# remove '500 GB Hard Disk'-symbol in computer:/// (nautilus)

Tags: nautilus, hard-drive

at the location computer:/// in nautilus i have a needless symbol '500 GB Hard Disk' how can I remove it?

it's like this problem:
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=117655

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and type `sudo blkid`

Copy the UUID of the drive you want to hide.

In the terminal type `gksudo gedit /etc/fstab`

Add a line `UUID=${UUID} none ntfs noowners,ro,noauto 0  0`. Change {UUID} with your UUID.

This will set the drive not to mount automatically, have no mount point, with no owner and read-only.

I'm not sure it won't show in computer:/// though. I haven't tested it.

Source: http://webapps.itcs.umich.edu/radmind/index.php/Hide_Windows_partition_in_dual_boot_setups

Comment: this drive is my file-system, i need it, so i have to mount it automatically..